# Dynamically calling on existing divs with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am very new to jQuery and I can't seem to figure this out...

I want to ask the user to enter an amount of days, at least 1 and at most 4.
So if they enter "3", then displayed would be:
Day 1
Day 2
Day 3

I can't figure out how to make these clickable, so that if day 2 is clicked, the content for div id day2 is displayed, and if they click on day 3, day 2 goes away and day 3 content appears.

My existing divs that I want to make appear, and where I get input from user to know how many days to display:

```js
$(window).load(function(){
  $('form').submit(function() {
    $('#days').empty();
    var inputNumber = $('#inputNumber').val(); 
    if (inputNumber>0) {
      for (i=0; i < inputNumber; i++) {
        $('<div id="#showdays' + i + '" />').text('Div: ' + (i+1)).appendTo('#days');
      }
    }
    return false;
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="days">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#day1">Day 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#day2">Day 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#day3">Day 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#day4">Day 4</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div id="day1">first day content</div>
  <div id="day2">second day content</div>
  <div id="day3">third day content</div>
  <div id="day4">fourth day content</div>
</div>

Below is where I get input from user to know how many days to display:


<form action="#" method="post">
  <label for="inputLabel">Number of days:</label>
  <input id="inputNumber" name="inputNumber" type="number" step="1"  min="1"  max="4"/>
  <input type="submit" value="Enter" />
</form>

<div id="days"></div>
```

I was thinking if making the divs into an array might help but I really don't know the best way to tackle this.
Any insight will help, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the first part you want to hide all the links when the page loads. Then set up an event listener - `input` or `click` events; either is fine. The use `:lt()` pseudo selector to select desired links and display.

Second part. Hide divs when the page loads. Then read the value of the `href` attribute to determine which one to display.

```js
$(function() {
    //Cache DOM searches so the searches do not have to be done at every event
    //Improrves overal speed of app
    var divs = $('#days > div[id]'); //or $('#days > .day');
    var links = $('#days li');
    divs.hide();
    $('#days li > a').on('click', function( e ) {
        e.preventDefault();
        divs.hide();
        var clickedID = $(this).attr('href');
        $( clickedID ).show();
    });
  

    $('#number').on('input', function() {
        var val = +this.value;
        if( val < this.min || val > this.max ) {
            this.value = '';
            return false;
        }
        links.hide();
        links.filter(':lt(' + (+this.value) + ')').show();
        divs.hide();
    })
    .trigger('input');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="number" name="number" id="number" min="1" max="4"  />
<div id="days">
   <ul>
    <li><a href="#day1">Day 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#day2">Day 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#day3">Day 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#day4">Day 4</a></li>
   </ul>
    <div id="day1" class="day">first day content</div>
    <div id="day2" class="day">second day content</div>
    <div id="day3" class="day">third day content</div>
    <div id="day4" class="day">fourth day content</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, this is what I was trying to do! Is there a way to hide the content if another number is typed in? For example if you type in 2, then click on Day 2, then you type in 1, the content from day 2 will still appear until you click on Day 1. Also is there a way to not allow typing a number higher than 4? I tried setting a min and max but that does not seem to work with this way.

Comment: Yes, of course. Check the updated version ... added `divs.hide();` in the `input` handler.

Comment: As for min and max, they're working fine on this demo in Chrome, if you're using the inc./dec. arrows. What browser and version are you testing on? Take a look at this page for browser support: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_form_input_types.asp. **To not allow anything other than 1-4 you may want to do validation. Will update shortly**

Comment: Thank you, it works great. I appreciate you explaining it as well, very helpful! However, I am kind of confused by what exactly is being done with " var divs = $('#days > div[id]');" if you don't mind explaining just that bit. Thank you!!

Comment: If all the `div`s with id `dayn` had a class, say `.day`, I would have written `var divs = $('#days > .day')`. This a technique of caching a jQuery search, that you're bound to perform several times, so as to improve the speed of your application. When cached like this, the search is done only once. DOM searches can consume precious resources; so you want to do as few as possible.

Comment: Glad you found this useful. Feel free to upvote this answer to indicate that, and to accept it if it is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

This is the code you are looking for in jQuery:

```js
$(window).load(function(){
  $('form').submit(function(e) {
    var inputNumber = $('#inputNumber').val();
    if (inputNumber>0) {
      $('div[id^="day"], #days > ul > li').not('#days').hide();
      $('#days > ul > li:lt(' + inputNumber + ')').show();
    }
    return false;
  });

  $('div[id^="day"], #days > ul > li').not('#days').hide();

  $(document).on('click', 'a[href^="#day"]', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('div[id^="day"]').not('#days').hide();
    $($(this).attr('href')).show();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form action="#" method="post">
    <label for="inputNumber">Number of days:</label>
    <input id="inputNumber" name="inputNumber" type="number" step="1"  min="1"  max="4"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Enter" />
</form>
<div id="days">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#day1">Day 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#day2">Day 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#day3">Day 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#day4">Day 4</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="day1">first day content</div>
    <div id="day2">second day content</div>
    <div id="day3">third day content</div>
    <div id="day4">fourth day content</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, but that is almost it, that's only what will happen if the user types in "4" within the form. If they type in 1, only Day 1 will show and that can be clicked. If they type in 2 only the first two days will show and can be clickable. Essentially trying to combine your code, with the code that I have posted after the form.

Comment: Yes that is more of what I was trying to accomplish, but the only thing is that the "days" divs are predefined so I have to have them included somehow outside of the script. <br> Say they type in 3, then Day 1 Day 2 Day 3 appear. If they press on Day 1, they will have a few questions that they need to answer that only exist in day 1. The questions in day 2 and day 3 will be very different, so that is why I need to use existing div's with their different contents showing when they are called on. I hope this makes sense? Maybe it is not possible?

Comment: Yes, that is the goal thank you very much for your help! I appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

```
<li><a href="#" class="dayLink" data-day="1">Day 1</a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="dayLink" data-day="2">Day 2</a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="dayLink" data-day="3">Day 3</a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="dayLink" data-day="4">Day 4</a></li>
<div class="day" data-day="1">first day content</div>
<div class="day" data-day="2">second day content</div>
<div class="day" data-day="3">third day content</div>
<div class="day" data-day="4">four day content</div>
```

**SCRIPT**

```
$(function(){
    var $days = $('.day');

    $('.dayLink').on('click', function(){
        var $link = $(this);

        $days.hide();
        $days.filter(function(){
            return $(this).data('day') === $link.data('day');
        }).show();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/m8p6ufcn/)

I have just added a couple of more classes `dayLink` and `dayContent` to make it easier to select them.

```
$('form').submit(

    function() {
      //$('#days').empty();
      var inputNumber = $('#inputNumber').val(); 
      if (inputNumber>0) 
      {
        for (i=0; i < inputNumber; i++) 
        {
            $('<div id="day'+ i +'" class="dayContent">day ' + i + ' content</div>').appendTo('#days');
            $('<li><a class="dayLink" href="#day'+ i +'">Day '+ i +'</a></li>').appendTo('#days ul');

        }
        $('div[id^="day"]').not('#days').hide();
      }
      return false;
  });

  $('#days').on('click', "a.dayLink", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var hrefValue = $( this ).attr( "href" );
    console.log( hrefValue );
    $( ".dayContent" ).hide();
    $( hrefValue ).show();
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for, in the end, is something like the following. I'll try to break down a full explanation of everything going on here later tonight.

```js
// method to add/remove days to output area
function showDays(e) {
 var iMax = parseInt($('#inpDays').val());
    for (i=0;i<4;i++) {
        if (i < iMax) {
            if (!$('#daysOut li').eq(i).length) $('#days-placeholders li').eq(i).clone().appendTo('#daysOut ul');
        }
        else $('#daysOut li').eq(i).remove();
    }
}
$(function() {  //  <-- same as $(document).ready
    //  these first 2 lines simply assign our show/remove days method to change event on input and click event on button
 $('#daysIn').on('change', 'input[type=number]', showDays);
 $('#daysIn').on('click', 'input[type=button]', showDays);
    //  the following adds click event to "dynamically" created content
    $('#daysOut').on('click', 'li a', function(e) {
     $(this).closest('li').addClass('selected').siblings('.selected').removeClass('selected').find('div').slideUp();
     $(this).next('div').slideDown();
    })
})
```

```css
#days-placeholders, .day .content { display: none; }

#daysOut { padding: 1em; }
#daysOut ul { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
#daysOut li { list-style: none; }
#daysOut li a { color: red; text-decoration: none; }
#daysOut li.selected a { color: blue; text-decoration: underline; }
#daysOut li div { max-width: 8em; padding: .25em .5em; text-align: center; }
#daysOut li.selected div { background: #00F7F7; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="days-placeholders">
    <ul>
        <li class="day day-1">
            <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn">Day 1</a>
            <div class="content">first day content</div>
        </li>
        <li class="day day-2">
            <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn">Day 2</a>
            <div class="content">second day content</div>
        </li>
        <li class="day day-3">
            <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn">Day 3</a>
            <div class="content">third day content</div>
        </li>
        <li class="day day-4">
            <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn">Day 4</a>
            <div class="content">fourth day content</div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div id="daysIn">
    <label for="inpDays">Number of days:</label>
    <input id="inpDays" name="inpDays" type="number" step="1" min="0" max="4" />
    <input id="btnSubmit" type="button" value="Enter" />
</div>
<div id="daysOut">
    <ul></ul>
</div>
```