# appending divs dynamically based on daterange with javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Check here: http://js.do/code/79682 
I am trying to figure out how to make it so that, when the date range is selected, the Dates that appear below are clickable and when they are clicked a div appears with the content for that date. So if Total Days: 5 then those 5 dates appear as links, when they are clicked the div content is displayed and if another div is clicked then the previous div closes and the new div content displays for the selected date. Every time I try incorporating the div "dates" it breaks the script.

Comment: your code cannot be modified in the link provided. Please create a project in codepen.io so that others can work on it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem that you are probably running into is that you are trying to set onclick event to something that doesn't exist, that's why you need to set .delegate(). The fix is at the bottom.

So try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    document.getElementById('dates').style.display = 'none';
    $( "#from" ).datepicker({
    altField: "#alternate",
    altFormat: "DD, d MM, yy",
    minDate: null,
    maxDate: "+60D",
    onSelect: function(selected) {
    $("#to").datepicker("option","minDate", selected);
    calcDiff();
 }
});

$( "#to" ).datepicker({
   altField: "#alternate1",
   altFormat: "DD, d MM, yy",
   minDate: new Date( (new Date()).getTime() + 86400000 ),
   maxDate:"+60D",
   onSelect: function(selected) {
   $("#from").datepicker("option","maxDate", selected);
   calcDiff();
}
});

function calcDiff() {

  var date1 = $('#from').datepicker('getDate');
  var date2 = $('#to').datepicker('getDate');
  var diff = 0;
  $('#totaldays').empty();
  if (date1 && date2) {
     diff = (Math.floor((date2.getTime() - date1.getTime()) / 86400000))+1;
     for(var d = date1.getTime(); d <= date2.getTime(); d = d + 86400000){
        $('#totaldays').append( '<a class="dates">' + $.datepicker.formatDate(   "MM d, yy", new Date(d) ) + "</a><br>");
    }
}
$('#calculated').val(diff);

}
 var tempDate;
 var closed;
 $('body').delegate('.dates', 'click', function() {
   var date = $(this).text();
   $(".createdDiv").remove();
   if(date != tempDate || closed){
       $(this).after( '<div class="createdDiv" style="height:100px;background-color:blue;"></div>' );
       closed = false;
    }
    else{
       closed = true;
    }
    tempDate = $(this).text();
});

});
```

Comment: This is kind of what I want except for this doesn't allow me to use predefined divs, because I have different content for each date for up to a total of 60 different dates. Doing it this way, doesn't allow me to have that fixed content anymore. The div id dates that I have initially in my code I was trying to iterate through them, the first date would match the first div, the second date will have the content of the second div, and so on. I'd add the other 58 after I got this working, is this not possible?

Comment: I found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34618628/dynamically-calling-on-existing-divs-with-jquery . The answer by user gaemaf is closest to what I am trying to accomplish but I don't know how to the same concept to the date-picker